# Python update the plot limits and multiple lines in the plot

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot, wxpython

I have some problems the first one is that I can't update the plot limits of the y axis and the second is that I want to see 6 lines from each sensor, as you can see in the picture I see only one if I make some changes I see all the sensors variations in one line

here is the code where I create the plot and a picture of this:

- http://i.imgur.com/ogFoMDJ.png?1

  ```
  # Flag variables
  self.isLogging = False

  # Create data buffers
  self.N = 70
  self.n = range(self.N)
  self.M = 6 # just one lead - i.e. 1 number per sample
  self.x = 0 * numpy.ones(self.N, numpy.int)

  # Data logging file
  self.f = 0

  # Create plot area and axes
  self.x_max = 500
  self.x_min = 330
  self.fig = Figure(facecolor='#e4e4e4')
  self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, self.fig)
  self.canvas.SetPosition((330,50))
  self.canvas.SetSize((550,280))
  self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0.08,0.1,0.86,0.8])
  self.ax.autoscale(False)
  self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.N - 1)
  self.ax.set_ylim(self.x_min, self.x_max)
  self.ax.plot(self.n,self.x)

  # Filter taps
  self.taps = [0, 0, 0]

  # Create timer to read incoming data and scroll plot
  self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
  self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.GetSample, self.timer)
  ```

And here is where I grab the data and I try to update the limits of the plot

```
    if len(sample_string) != 6:

        sample_string = sample_string[0:-1]
        self.taps[1:3] = self.taps[0:2]
        self.taps[0] = int(array[1])
        #value = 0.5 * self.taps[0] + 0.5 * self.taps[2]
        value = self.taps[0]
        self.x[0:self.N-1] = self.x[1:]
        self.x[self.N-1] = value
        # print sample to data logging file
        if self.f != 0:
            self.f.write(str(value))
            self.f.write("\n")

        # update plot limits
        maxval = max(self.x[:])
        minval = min(self.x[:])
        self.x_max += ((maxval + 10) - self.x_max) / 100.0
        self.x_min -= (self.x_min - (minval - 10)) / 100.0

    # Update plot
    self.ax.cla()
    self.ax.autoscale(False)
    self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.N - 1)
    self.ax.set_ylim(self.x_min, self.x_max)
    self.ax.plot(self.n, self.x)
    self.canvas.draw() 

    if b7 == True:
        self.textctrl0.Clear()
        self.textctrl0.AppendText(array[1])
        self.textctrl1.Clear()
        self.textctrl1.AppendText(array[2])
        self.textctrl2.Clear()
        self.textctrl2.AppendText(array[3])   
        self.textctrl3.Clear()
        self.textctrl3.AppendText(array[4])
        self.textctrl4.Clear()
        self.textctrl4.AppendText(array[5])
        self.textctrl5.Clear()
        self.textctrl5.AppendText(array[6])
        b7=False
```

p.s I removed the faulty code where I tried to add the other sensors,here is only the working code for the one sensor plot..

Comment: It would be nice if you can create a minimal running example which demonstrates the problem. http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it's hard to do that because is a bit complex the code and long, but I want to create something like this (second example) http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/ ,but only as how this plot works and the difference that I want six lines.

Comment: That is the problem. Your code is long and complex, but not really tied to your question. It is hard to understand and we cannot run it and see the problem ourselves.

Comment: If I make a running example still you can't see the problem because the data comes from an arduino. This part of code works but only with one sensor which I take the data from 'array1'.I can update the plot limits of the x axis but I don't know how to do it for the y axis.

Comment: You can use random data if the problem is only tied to visualization.

Comment: But maybe someone more experienced will see the problem off hand, so no rush.

Comment: As @Fenikso says, there is too much irrelevant code here.  Can you make a _minimal_ example that pulls data from a random source?